# Select tag with blank textbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, textbox

I have done a form which retrieves data from the database. This form allows you to display the list of students from the database but the problem is I cannot correctly input their scores individually. It does allow to insert scores but unfortunately, it only accepts the last score from the last student and inputs the same score to all students.

These are my codes:

FORM code

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row['status']=='p'){


    <form name="result" method="post"> 
    <?php {          //this form will display the set of students

            echo $row['lastname'] . ', ' . $row['firstname'];
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="selected[]" value="'.$row['reviewee_idnumber'].'"/>'; ?>
            <input type="text" name="score" required="required" size="20" placeholder="Score"/><br><br>
    <?php   echo '</br>';
        }


    } //if statement
    } //while statement
    ?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="<?php echo $code;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="<?php echo $subject;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="items" value="<?php echo $items;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo $date;?>"/>
</form>
```

This is where I insert my code into the database

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$code = $_POST['code'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$items = $_POST['items'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$score = $_POST['score']; //get score

$update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO exam (exam_code, subject, date, total_item)
                                    VALUE ('$code','$subject', '$date', '$items')"); 


if(!empty($_POST['selected'])) {       
    $checked_count = count($_POST['selected']);// Counting number of checked checkboxes.
    //echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>"; 

    foreach($_POST['selected'] as $selected){  // Loop to store and display values of individual inputs.
         $updatedata="INSERT INTO result (score, exam_code, reviewee_idnumber) 
                                    VALUE ('$score', '$code', '$selected')";


            if(@mysql_query($updatedata,$dbc)){
                print '<p> successful!</p>';  
            }else{
                print '<p> failed. '.mysql_error().'</p>';
            }
```

It should display list students (which is fine) and right beside their name is a blank space that will accept their score (which doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Because `<form name="result" method="post">` is inside the while loop, you actually have multiple forms in your page. The submit button acts only on the last form, that's why only the last student's score gets updated.

Also, because there are multiple `input` elements with the same `name`, only a single value is sent in the POST request. A solution for this would be to include the student's ID in the name:

```
name="score'.$row['reviewee_idnumber'].'"
```

You need to update the form processing logic accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried to re-code the
<form name="result" method="post">  and placed it before the while loop but it does not work. The users with different reviewee_idnumber works perfectly but the scores does not. What else do you might suggest?

Comment: Use different `name`s for each input field - see my updated answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work though but thanks for the idea! Will go deeper. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
name =<?php echo "'score.$row['reviewee_idnumber']'" ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!